# Backbone integration tests: Zombie.js and RequireJS, how to?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test my [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) web application.
Since this application is basically only consuming web services, there is not really business logic inside, and the app is simply addressing calls to our API.

I'd like to use [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) for ma integration test suit, which works - for the moment - with **Karma** and **Jasmine**.

My problem is I'm using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), and because Zombie doesn't seem to be AMD compliant, I can't import Zombie into my test view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you include zombie js in your test runner? I think karma has a files array in its config

source: http://toon.io/how-to-setup-karma-javascript-test-runner/